# Set Mapbox projection to be compatible with EPSG:27700

Tags: mapbox, wgs84, proj, epsg

I have 5m rasters that I am adding as layers to mapbox. The rasters themselves are projected in EPSG:27700 (OSGB36), whereas mapbox is projected in WGS84.

Because of this I am getting certain inconsistencies when trying to retrieve the values of the raster based on the converted lngLat coords retrieved when clicking Mapbox. I am using Proj4 to convert between projections.

```
const wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

const osgb36 = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";

let [orig_x, orig_y] = this.convertProj(wgs84, osgb36, lon, lat);

requestFromRaster(source, orig_x, orig_y);

this.createMarker([lon, lat]);

/** converts the coordinates from lon and lat to BNG, the projection of our raster data */

convertProj (projFrom, projTo, lon, lat) {
    return proj4(projFrom, projTo, [lon, lat]);
},
```

Is it better to:

a) Project the rasters from OSGB36 to WGS84 beforehand?

b) Convert mapbox to be using the OSGB36 projection?

c) Something else I haven't thought about.

I would like to use option `b`, but am not sure if that is the correct method or permitted in mapbox.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/projections/) help?

Comment: Mapbox supports only these projections: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/projection/. So a) is your only option.

Comment: @TomazicM, thanks. I reprojected original data and created the xyz tile images from it. I then followed the instructions here: towardsdatascience.com/geotiff-coordinate-querying-with-javascript-5e6caaaf88cf,  so that when I click on the map to get lat and lon I can read from the raster file. However, they still don't quite line up. Is it actuall possible to get accuracy within 5m?

Comment: This is different question. Please post it as separate question, with all the necessary  details of what exactly does not line up.

Comment: @TomazicM - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/437282/inconsistencies-between-xyz-images-in-mapbox-and-raster