# Inconsistencies between xyz images in Mapbox and raster

Tags: raster, gdal, mapbox, gdal2tiles, xyz

I have a 5m raster that I want to show on `Mapbox`. Using `gdal2tiles.py` I created the xyz images and am serving them from s3 up to zoom level 18. The idea is that the user should be able to click on a pixel and from the `lat` and `lon` provided by `Mapbox`, retrieve the value from the original raster as outlined here https://towardsdatascience.com/geotiff-coordinate-querying-with-javascript-5e6caaaf88cf.

The problem is that when I click on the map where there is no `xyz` image I get a value from the raster. It also happens where I get no value when I should. It's made more confusing by the fact that it's inconsistently wrong - i.e sometimes it seems values are shifted to the right, left, up or down in different places, so I can't just correct it that way.

I thought it was a problem with projection, so I converted the raster from `EPSG:27700` to `EPSG:4326` to match the projection of `Mapbox`, but these inconsistencies still occur.

One thing I noticed in `QGIS` compared to the image on `Mapbox` is that there seem to be fewer pixels on `Mapbox` - so I am thinking the error is in the `xyz` image rather than retrieving the value from the raster.

I am new to all this and am finding this aspect fairly confusing.

What I want is to click on the image and get the exact corresponding value from the raster. How can I achieve this.

The command to generate the images is:
`gdal2tiles.py raster.tif --xyz --zoom=8-18 --processes=4 --exclude`

To convert the raster between projections:
`gdalwarp -s_srs 'EPSG:27700' -t_srs 'EPSG:4326' raster.tif raster.tif`

To retrieve the value from the raster based on lat and lon from mapbox:

```
const bbox = image.getBoundingBox();
const pixelWidth = image.getWidth();
const pixelHeight = image.getHeight();
const bboxWidth = bbox[2] - bbox[0];
const bboxHeight = bbox[3] - bbox[1];
const widthPct = (lon - bbox[0]) / bboxWidth;
const heightPct = (lat - bbox[1]) / bboxHeight;
const xPx = Math.floor(pixelWidth * widthPct);
let yPx = Math.floor(pixelHeight * (1 - heightPct));
const window = [xPx, yPx, xPx + 1, yPx + 1];
const data = await image.readRasters({ window });
const finalValue = data[0][0];
```

screenshot of where there should be a value. Anything pink should have a value, and anything not should not have a value
[image]

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: @TomazicM, ok I have added more detail. Let me know if you need any more